# JADE Multi-agent adding elements into JSON Array

Tags: java, agents-jade, multi-agent

I am having a problem with adding elements to JSON array iteratively using JADE Multi agent platform.
For example, the original JSON array was {["a","b","c]}.
I want my result to be {["a","b","c","1","2"]}.
The JSOn Array element adding should be placed inside a cyclic behaviour.
I got something like this.

```
i=1
JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
jsonObj.put("char",array);

addBehaviour(new TickerBehaviour(this,3000) {
array.add( i);
i++;
}
```

But the result was:

```
{["a","b","c","1"]}
{["a","b","c","2"]}
```

Comment: Where are you adding a, b, c to the array? Also, char should be in the output. Please show a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need to overwrite the previous object value with the updated one

```
array.add(i++);
jsonObj.put("char",array);
```

Comment: Hi. I actually want to add the new value to the array not overwrite. The desired result should be:{["a","b","c","1"]} then {["a","b","c","1","2"]}

Comment: This does add a value to the array... It overwrites the array previously in the outer object

Comment: You should get `{"char":[1]}` then  `{"char":[1, 2]}` with the code posted and this solution